# how to display values from database into the layout page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, controller

Here i am trying to make a dynamic and editable layout page in mvc.In my layout page i have a logo( which is presently hard coded). I am implementing a function so that any user can change that logo by uploading his own logo.**The path of that logo is stored in database.** For example if this is my logo now :

```
<img alt="" src="~/Images/W_logo.png" style="border-style: none;" width="115px" height="60px" />
```

I want it to be something like :

```
<img alt="" src="@item.logo" style="border-style: none;" width="115px" height="60px" />
```

where 'logo' is a parameter i pass in my model.

or

```
 <img alt="" src="@ViewData["logopath']" style="border-style: none;" width="115px" height="60px" />
```

Also if i am using a controller to store the value how can i make it so that it runs everytime the application starts. For example is this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult layoutChange()
{
  --recover path from database--
  ViewData["logopath"]=path from the database;
  return View(); -- Here the view is the layout page
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you try to use `Html.RenderAction` in your _Layout.cshtml page.  You can use this to specify a controller action to invoke.

The controller action can then '*recover path from database*' as you indicated, and pass this path to a partial view that contains the markup for your `img` tag.  The result of all of that will become part of the dynamic markup for your _Layout page.

By taking this approach, you don't need to pass the path value to the _Layout page.  What happens is the _Layout page calls the controller (via Html.RenderAction), and the controller figures out the path and returns the entire IMG tag markup.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.One thing i want to know is that u mentioned that the controller will pass the path to a partial view. Instead of partial view cant it directly pass to layout page?

Comment: Here's an article that provides an approach to 'strongly-typing' a layout page [link](http://philjthorne.blogspot.com/2012/05/strongly-typing-aspnet-mvc-masterlayout.html).  This approach is arguably somewhat limiting, but I haven't been able to find another way to do specifically what you're describing.